# Bibliographic entry not show the paper's title correctly

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I want to cite a paper with a following `.bib` file:

```
@article{almassalkhi2015model,
  title={Model-predictive cascade mitigation in electric power systems with storage and renewables—Part II: Case-study},
  author={Almassalkhi, Mads R and Hiskens, Ian A},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Systems},
  volume={30},
  number={1},
  pages={78--87},
  year={2015},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

however in the reference section, title of cited paper has not been shown correctly:

> M. R. Almassalkhi and I. A. Hiskens, “Model-predictive cascade
>   mitigation in electric power systems with storage and renewablespart
>   ii: Case-study,” IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, vol. 30, no. 1,
>   pp. 78–87, 2015.

"renewablespart ii" is the part that expected to be "renewables—Part II".

Does any one know why it is like this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you try putting `{` and `}`, i.e. use e.g. ` title={Model-predictive cascade mitigation in electric power systems with storage and renewables—{Part II}: {C}ase-study},`?

Comment: putting between { and } fixed the ii to II problem, however, it still skips "-" between renewables and Part  as "renewablespart II" . do you have any idea how it can be fixed.

Comment: Try the same, i.e. `title={Model-predictive cascade mitigation in electric power systems with storage and {renewables—Part II}: {C}ase-study},`.

Comment: @marmot tried but did not help, still it ignores the "dash"

Comment: My problem is that your format differs from the one I am familiar with (see e.g. [here](http://inspirehep.net/record/52295/export/hx)) in that you use brackets instead of quotation marks. Why is that? My final attempts: `title={Model-predictive cascade mitigation in electric power systems with storage and {renewables{$-$}Part II}: {C}ase-study}` and `title="Model-predictive cascade mitigation in electric power systems with storage and {renewables—Part II}: {C}ase-study"`. Hope you find some more competent reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has two parts:

1. To get uppercase letters you need to enclose them with `{}` like `{II}`. Do that for all uppercase letter you want to get printed. If you omit the brackets you get lowercase letters instead.
2. In your code `renewables—Part` you have used an en-dash. Use instead the en-dash better `--`.

So with the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{almassalkhi2015model,
  title     = {Model-predictive cascade mitigation in electric power 
               systems with storage and renewables--{P}art {II}: 
               {C}ase-study},
  author    = {Almassalkhi, Mads R and Hiskens, Ian A},
  journal   = {IEEE Transactions on Power Systems},
  volume    = {30},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {78--87},
  year      = {2015},
  publisher = {IEEE},
}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: wished result]